# Query range date not exist in range date in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, range

I have range date like this in db:

[image]

I want to create a query return true/false when @FromDate and @Todate param input not exist in db.

Ex:

@Fromdate: 2024-01-18 | @ToDate: 2024-01-21 => true

@Fromdate: 2024-01-18 | @ToDate: 2024-01-24 => false

@Fromdate: 2024-01-06 | @ToDate: 2024-01-08 => false

@Fromdate: 2024-01-09 | @ToDate: 2024-01-09 => true

How can I do it

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use table markdown

Comment: And please provide a [mre]

Comment: Have you had a look at `EXISTS`? What *have* you look at? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided data and desired results, the OP is looking for a way to determine whether two date ranges overlap or not :

```
select s.*, case when t.StartDate is not null then 'false' else 'true' end as not_overlap
from  (
  select '2024-01-18' as StartDate, '2024-01-21' as EndDate union all
  select '2024-01-18', '2024-01-24' union all
  select '2024-01-06', '2024-01-08' union all
  select '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09'
) as s 
left join mytable t on t.StartDate <= s.EndDate and t.EndDate >= s.StartDate;
```

Results :

```
StartDate   EndDate     not_overlap
2024-01-18  2024-01-21  true
2024-01-18  2024-01-24  false
2024-01-06  2024-01-08  false
2024-01-09  2024-01-09  true
```

See :

- [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/4286884)

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/piF8uo56)